# Why does a second vertical scroll bar appear in this Bootstrap 3.0 Modal demo?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Scroll down a bit on this Bootstrap 3.0 (WIP) page to the 'Launch Demo Modal'.

http://bs3.codersgrid.com/javascript/#modals

Notice a second vertical scroll bar appears. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the CSS style being applied to the element:

```
.modal {
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* <--- this guy right here */
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
}
```

Explicitly setting an overflow property to `scroll` will cause the browser to display a scrollbar whether there is overflow or not.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I missed that because I just assumed that would be set for modals by default. I also assumed it was a Bootstrap 3.0 WIP 'bug'. My bad for being on the 'bleeding edge' and making bad assumptions.

Comment: @Eric It happens to the best of us. No worries ;)

Comment: Hm, the current demo shows only one scrollbar, but my code has two, which makes the page jump.

Answer (score 2):

Completely remove the html tag from your style sheet. This will fix it.

Comment: That suggestion works actually than the selected answer... anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*remove double scrollbar*/
body.modal-open { overflow: hidden!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried each example that I found from stackoverflow and finally this is my solution:**

```
$(function(){
$(document.body).on("show.bs.modal", function () {

        $(window.document).find("html").addClass("modal-open");

        $(window.document).find("div.wrapper").css({"margin-right":"17px"});

    });

    $(document.body).on("hide.bs.modal", function () {

        $(window.document).find("html").removeClass("modal-open");

        $(window.document).find("div.wrapper").removeAttr("style"); 

    });

});

$(function(){

    $(document.body).on("show.bs.modal", function () {

        $(document.body).addClass("modal-open");

    });

    $(document.body).on("hide.bs.modal", function () {

        $(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");

    });

});
```