# In Bootstrap 3.0 Modal, Scroll bar disabled but it still occupies space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

This question is related to this:-

[Why does a second vertical scroll bar appear in this Bootstrap 3.0 Modal demo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666543/why-does-a-second-vertical-scroll-bar-appear-in-this-bootstrap-3-0-modal-demo)

Ok. I've override the `.modal` class `overflow-y` rule:-

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

But now when the modal opens I do not see scroll bar. That's fine. That is what I required. However, it still consumes the space, and the page moves towards the left whenever the modal opens.

screenshot:-

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Look at this bug in Github. Scroll down to close to the end for a few solutions: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Culprit caught. Bootstrap adds a class to the body and other areas with the following name and rule:-

```
body.modal-open, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
     margin-right:15px;
}
```

also override this class as follows, and it'll be fine.

```
body.modal-open, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
     margin-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *auto* give *hidden*.

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of after open modal, modal is adding class "modal-open" to body tag.

to resolve this

You can override CSS as below

`body.modal-open {
    overflow-y: auto;
}`

but still you will see another disable scroll bar at side. 
to resolve that

you can override as below

`.modal{
    overflow-y: auto;
}`